# how to use "apoc.util.md5" in embedded neo4j

Tags: neo4j, md5, neo4j-apoc, neo4j-embedded

I find some code examples here about enabling APOC in embedded neo4j.

It is something like that i need to register the procedure's class.
(but lack of description. wonder if there is official tutorial of that)

I have added this in my pom.xml : `http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j.procedure/apoc/3.3.0.4`

And I guess there should be a class like `apoc.util.Md5` to register, but it is seem no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On an embedded database you need to register your functions and procedures, can you try this :

```
(GraphDatabaseAPI) getDatabase()).getDependencyResolver().resolveDependency(Procedures.class).registerFunction(apoc.util.Utils.class)
```

Cheers